# Added/deleted blockquote displayed with bigger height in revisions

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, blockquote

If while editing a post a blockquote [was added or deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/301787/revisions) then this block is displayed with bigger height than non-deleted:

> [image: revisions]

Non-deleted block in revisions page is dislplayed same as in the post itself.